# Change Sources TAB background color

Tags: css, google-chrome, background, web-inspector

Is possible to change Chrome's `Sources` tab background color? I found [**this**](http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/) article, it explains how to give a custom skin to Chrome's inspector through a css file, but it doesn't work for the Sources tab (Elements and Console work very well though, as you can see from the screenshot)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some themes don't change `Sources` tab color. Different themes, different styles. Try to use something else. I would recommend these ones (all of them change `Sources` tab background color):

MNML: https://github.com/frontdevde/mnml-devtools-theme/blob/master/Custom.css
[image]
Ruby Blue: https://github.com/chrisbateman/ChromeDevToolsTheme-RubyBlue/blob/master/Custom.css
[image]
Tomorrow: https://gist.github.com/bentruyman/1163300
[image]

Do the same steps, but use one of `Custome.css` files I mentioned above.